# Unity ADS работает на 10 андроиде и не работает на 5 или 7

Tags: android, unity3d, ads

Написал приложение, подключил монетизацию. Приложение перестало запускаться на 5 и 7 андроиде и спокойно работает на 10. Удаляю монетизацию - все везде работает.  Подумал, может косяк в монетизации и создал пустое тестовое приложение, в нем монетизация работает и запускается на всех телефонах. Пробовал подключать Unity monetization из ассет стора, пробовал через пакедж менеджер, пробовал просто добавлять advertisement. Пробовал собрать все в юнити 2019 и в 2020. Ничего не меняется. В чем может быть проблема? Куда смотреть, где искать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение. У меня в игре земля состояла из кучи дублированных блоков и на каждом висел скрипт перезапуска сцены. И в нем же висел скрипт рекламы. Телефоны до 10 андроида просто видимо по железу не могут все это обработать. Переделал, решил проблему.